# mPDF footer is not showing

Tags: php, html, footer, mpdf

I am using a basic html structure for my PDF template together with `<htmlpagefooter>` according to the [mPDF docs](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/html-control-tags/sethtmlpagefooter.html).
A sample implementation can be found [here](https://mpdf.github.io/headers-footers/method-4.html)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
        .mydiv {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <htmlpagefooter name="myfooter">
      Page {PAGENO} of {nb}
  </htmlpagefooter>

  <sethtmlpagefooter name="myfooter" value="on" />
  <body>
    <div class="mydiv">
        This is my PDF file
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I generate my PDF it will refuse to show the footer on any page. When I put PHP code inside it will throw an appropriate error proving that it is parsed into the mPDF.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using a `<body>` tag inside an `<html>` tag, you have to make sure your footer is included in code that will be rendered on a page.

When you include the footer ***outside*** of the body, it will not be shown in the PDF.

When you include the footer ***inside*** the body, it will render as expected.

So a succesfull implementation of a footer in mPDF would look like this;

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
        .mydiv {
            color: red;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <htmlpagefooter name="myfooter">
        Page {PAGENO} of {nb}
    </htmlpagefooter>
  
    <sethtmlpagefooter name="myfooter" value="on" />
    <div class="mydiv">
        This is my PDF file
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```